# Error copying worksheet data into array

Tags: excel, vba

i need to copy data from an Excel range into an array. I am using the following code, but it is showing the error "expected array."

```
  Dim filename As String
  Dim arraysize As Integer

  arraysize = 50
  I = 1
  Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 1).Value = ""   
     filename(arraysize) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 1).Value    
     I = I + 1
  Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim filename As Variant
    Dim arraysize As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With

    ' load as two dimensional array
    filename = rng.Value

    ' transform into 1 dimensional array
    filename = Application.Transpose(filename)

    arraysize = UBound(filename)
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nicely Done :) I guess the use of `i` is not required and can be plugged in the code it self :) I am also kind of skeptical on the use of `xlDown` to find the lastrow. My fav method is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Thank Siddharth.  I left `i` in on the assumption this is a code fragment of a larger app, where `i` has some significance.  I used `xlDown` to replicate the OP code behaviour - as you know, this acts from `i` down to the first blank row, which many or may not be the last used row (although I admit I haven't covered the cases where cell at `i` is blank, or there is only one non-blank cell starting at `i`)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't declared the array. I can't think of the code off the top of my head but this should point you in the right direction.

```
Dim Filename(50)

Do
    Filename(I)= excel.row
Loop
```